# Renaming a Table in SymmetricDS with Transform

Tags: mysql, rename, symmetricds

I would like to use symmetricDS to copy a table from a client node to a master node but with a different name of the table at the master node. I use "transform" in order to rename the table. It works fine if my renamed table is located in the master node schema (where also all of the master sym tables are located).

But, I have two issues:

a) At the moment I always need to create the whole target table layout before syncing. Is it possible that symmetricDS automatically creates the renamed target table?

b) Renaming a table doesn't work anymore if I locate my renamed table in a different database (called master_db), even though I specify the target_catalog_name everywhere it is required.

I'm thankful for any help regarding this issue.

Below is the code I use for setting up the master and the client nodes.

-- config master node:

```
    INSERT INTO `symmetricds_master`.`sym_node_group` (`node_group_id`)
    VALUES ('master_node');

    INSERT INTO `symmetricds_master`.`sym_node_group_link` 
    (`source_node_group_id`,`target_node_group_id`,`data_event_action`) 
    VALUES ('client_node', 'master_node', 'P');

    INSERT INTO `symmetricds_master`.`sym_node_group_link` 
    (`source_node_group_id`, `target_node_group_id`, `data_event_action`) 
    VALUES ('master_node', 'client_node', 'W');
```

-- config client node:

```
    insert into  symmetricds.`SYM_ROUTER` 
    (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_catalog_name,target_node_group_id,create_time,last_update_time) 
    values ('client2master','client_node','master_db','master_node',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

    insert into symmetricds.sym_trigger 
    (trigger_id,source_catalog_name, source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
    values ('TriggerA','source_db','ATable','default',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

    insert into symmetricds.sym_trigger_router 
    (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time)
    values ('TriggerA', 'client2master', 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

    insert into symmetricds.sym_transform_table 
    (transform_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,transform_point,source_catalog_name,source_table_name,target_catalog_name,target_table_name,delete_action,column_policy)
    values ('TransfAtoB', 'client_node', 'master_node', 'Load','source_db','ATable','master_db','BTable', 'DEL_ROW', 'IMPLIED');
```

Answer (score 0):

My first observation is that there are two different symmetricDs configuration database schemas. That's not needed. It's enough to have one master symmetricDs configuration database -- at the central node, let all clients upon registration to download the relevant configuration and apply it to their local symmetricDs schemas.

> a) At the moment I always need to create the whole target table layout
>   before syncing. Is it possible that symmetricDS automatically creates
>   the renamed target table?

Use DDL commands admin commands to create a missing table on the destination node

> b) Renaming a table doesn't work anymore if I locate my renamed table
>   in a different database (called master_db), even though I specify the
>   target_catalog_name everywhere it is required.

You should be having one master_db. Why would you locate the table in another database?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. a) So, you say there is no procedure to create the renamed table at the destination without using DDL admin commands? I thought this should be possible. b) In principle when specifying target_catalog_name this feature should be available.

Comment: a) as far as I know it's the only way; b) have you tried it?